# CSV File Date Formatting

Tags: linux, shell-script, command-line

Here is the short version of my question: how do you convert comma-separated lists of dates from one format to another? More specifically, I'd like a single one-line command which converts strings of this form:

```
YYYY/MM/DD,YYYY/MM/DD
```

to strings of the following form:

```
DD/MM/YYYY,DD/MM/YYYY
```

Now I'll describe the context for my question.

I have a CSV file whose rows contain pairs of adjacent dates in the following format:

```
YYYY/MM/DD
```

I run the following `grep` command to extract the pair of dates:

```
grep -Po '[1-2][0-1][0-9][0-9]/[0-1][0-9]/[0-1][0-9]','[1-2][0-1][0-9][0-9]/[0-1][0-9]/[0-1][0-9]' file.csv`
```

This results, for example, in strings such as the following:

```
2016/05/16,2017/06/15
```

I am able to convert a single date-string using the `date` command as follows:

```
date -d '2016/05/16' '+%d/%m/%Y'
```

This produces the desired result:

```
16/05/2016
```

I tried applying this command to multiple input strings, e.g.:

```
date -d"2016/05/16","2017/06/15" "+%d-%m-%Y"
```

But that didn't work. I received the following error message:

```
Error :- Invalid date - 2016/05/16,2017/06/15'
```

What I want is a single command which will convert `2016/05/16,2017/06/15` to `16/05/2016,15/06/2017`.

Comment: post the input fragment of your `file.csv`

Comment: I think I understand what you're asking and I posted a solution, but this post is pretty difficult to parse. You might want to read about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @igal  I found it to be a very clear question.

Comment: @fpmurphy1 Thanks! I rewrote it. ;)

Comment: Does the ```grep``` actually have anything to do with this question? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which extends your use of the `date -d` command. It only uses shell-scripting and the standard GNU command-line tools `tr` and `paste`:

```
tr ',' '\n' \
| while read line; do date -d "${line}" "+%d/%m/%Y"; done \
| paste -d, -s -
```

We use `tr` to convert the comma to a newline, splitting the one line of input into two. Then we pipe these two lines to a `while` loop and apply the `date` formatting command to each line. Finally, we pipe the converted date-strings to `paste` in order to recombine them into a single comma-separated list.

Here is what it looks like with your example input:

```
echo 2016/05/16,2017/06/15 \
| tr ',' '\n' \
| while read line; do date -d "${line}" "+%d/%m/%Y"; done \
| paste -d, -s -
```

And here is the output it produces:

```
16/05/2016,15/06/2017
```

Combining this with the `grep` command in your post, we get the following:

```
grep -Po '[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-1][0-9]/[0-1][0-9]','[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-1][0-9]/[0-1][0-9]' file.csv \
| tr ',' '\n' \
| while read line; do date -d "${line}" "+%d/%m/%Y"; done \
| paste -d, -s -
```

You might also want to shorten the regular expression that you're using with `grep`. Maybe something like this will also work (note that it matches a trailing comma):

```
grep -Po '([12][0-9]{3}(/[01][0-9]){2},?){2}' file.csv
```

Finally, we can use output redirection to write the results to a file:

```
grep -Po '[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-1][0-9]/[0-1][0-9]','[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-1][0-9]/[0-1][0-9]' file.csv \
| tr ',' '\n' \
| while read line; do date -d "${line}" "+%d/%m/%Y"; done \
| paste -d, -s - \
> new_file.csv
```

Comment: I am not sure this will grep year from previous century (e.g. 1999/09/13) as second digit must be either 0 or 1.

Comment: @Archemar I thought that I had just translated your regular expression. Maybe there was a typo in your original post? Anyway, that's easy enough to fix - done!

Comment: I am not the OP, and those regexp are a bit curious to match date ...

Comment: @Archemar Whoops! Sorry, my mistake. And yes, I agree that the regular expressions aren't ideal, but that wasn't really the point of the post (and the OP also didn't say anything about needing to validate the dates) so I didn't want to get bogged down in that.

Comment: Hi guys... I tried above code.. and it's work but I want to save reformatted date in back to CSV file. How can i do it.

Comment: @Kaushal I updated my solution. Look at the new command at the bottom of the post.

Comment: While `date` is indeed a standard command, the `-d` option is not. Also note that standardly, `paste` needs at least one filename argument (here, you'd use `-`). The `-P` and `-o` options to `grep` are also not standard. Note that the behaviour of `read` depends on the current value of `$IFS`. There's nothing `bash`-specific in your command. It would also work with the standard `sh` utility

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thank you for the comment. I was using `date -d` because I was I trying to extend the solution used in the OP. I modified the language of my post to reflect that and to note that I was using the GNU toolset. After reflecting on your comment and looking at the [man page for the POSIX date command](https://github.com/sourcegraph/man-pages-posix/blob/master/man1p/date.1p.txt) I realized that I don't know a good way to do date conversion portably at the shell. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Using sed ...

```
echo "2016/05/16,2017/06/15" | sed 's/\([0-9]\{4\}\)\/\([0-9]\{2\}\)\/\([0-9]\{2\}\),\([0-9]\{4\}\)\/\([0-9]\{2\}\)\/\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\3\/\2\/\1,\6\/\5\/\4/g'
16/05/2016,15/06/2017
```